# Calculate shifted unit circle values

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

I have the black unit circle and I need to shift it by x degrees getting the red unit circle. How do I shift it, because just subtracting x degrees from the original black circle doesn't work.

[image]

EDIT:
The red values are the new values which I need to calculate relative to the original black values.

Comment: I'm not sure what's required here. Do you need to produce a rotation matrix? Do you need to phase shift sine and cosine to fit a new definition for your unit circle? Why is the original circle progress clockwise with $0^\circ$ at the top? Perhaps add detail from the original question or let us know what class this is part of (if from a class).

Comment: In the first place the red value is not uniquely determined by the black value: There are two points on the circle with black value $45$. One of them gets red value $0$, and the other gets red value $90$.